# How to show static HTML page in android emulator?

Tags: android

I want to display one static HTML page in my android emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to display your own page in a webview?

Create this as your activity:

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        try {
            InputStream fin = getAssets().open("index.html");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            fin.read(buffer);
            fin.close();
            webview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This will read the file 'index.html' from your project assets/ folder.

Comment: i tried this example but it only read source code of the html file in web view only the source is displaying.

Answer (score 11):

an easier way is described at [Android HTML resource with references to other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295381/android-html-resource-with-references-to-other-resources). Its working fine for me.

Put the HTML file in the "assets" folder in root, load it using:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

Comment: **Important:** The URL is not misspelled.  It should be `android_asset`, not `android_assets`.

Answer (score 0):

So you can simply use the WebView control to display web content to the screen, which can think of the WebView control as a browser-like view.

You can also dynamically formulate an HTML string and load it into the WebView, using the loadData() method. It takes three arguments. String htmlData, String mimeType and String encoding

First of all you create a **“test.html”** file and save it into assets folder.

**Code:**

```
<html>
<Body bgcolor=“yellow”>
<H1>Hello HTML</H1> 
<font color=“red”>WebView Example by Android Devloper</font>
</Body> </html>
```

if you want see full source code : [Display HTML Content in Android](http://theandroid.in/how-to-display-html-content-in-android/)