# Android HTML resource with references to other resources

Tags: html, android, resources, embedded-resource, drawable

I would like to add an HTML resource to my Android project with references to other resources (mainly drawables).

Where should I put it and how do I reference other resources from it?

Is there a particular way to pass the HTML resource to a `WebView`?

Thanks!

Comment: The following question might give a more clear picture.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892753/how-to-show-static-html-page-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The html file goes into the assets folder in root (as a sibling folder of res), as well as all the drawables. You can view it by doing something like

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

Comment: Thanks EboMike. And how do you reference other non-asset resources from the html file? Can't they be drawables?

Comment: It's HTML, so you need to make it work so WebKit can render it. I assume that you can simply use <img src="image.jpg"> and place that image into the assets folder. If you have dynamic drawables, you could save them to the sdcard and reference them using "file:///sdcard/image.jpg". This is off the top of my head, the syntax may be incorrect.

Comment: What about BitmapDrawables? I would like to avoid duplicating the files (one copy in res/drawables, the other in assets) to keep the file size of the app down.

Comment: WebKit can't access your apps' resources. I wonder if you could do something exotic and create your own content provider, something like myapp://pictures/picture.jpg, which grabs resources and sends them back. But that's overkill. If you copy them to the SD card, they at least won't count against internal storage. There may be a better solution, but nothing obvious that comes to mind.

Alternatively, you could try to create your images from bitmaps in the assets folder - just load them like you would load external image files and create Drawables out of them.

Comment: Having it in assets also means it can't be in a library project as you would have to copy these assets into all app projects that use the library or use another library that uses the library.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is on the SD card, this reference will work:

content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/filename.jpg