# Android:how use to my file

Tags: android

How can use in my raw(html file) to webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something that was asked a few days ago. Check out my answer here: [Android HTML resource with references to other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295381/android-html-resource-with-references-to-other-resources/3295535#3295535)

(This is regarding HTML files in the assets block, but I hope this works for you as well.)

Comment: Could whoever voted this down have the courtesy to explain why?

Answer (score -1):

You would use a WebView.  Instantiate a WebView, and then call the method:  `webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");  // 'summary' is your raw html...`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: but, loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); summary must String type. I want to call from(R.raw.part.html). Thank anyway.